# Small group size inference for logistic regression

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logistic, binary-data

Please note this analysis is being done retrospectively (i.e., all data have been collected).

I have a binary response variable $y_i \in \{0, 1\}$ and two covariates $x_{1i}$ and $x_{2i}$. $x_{1i}$ is meant to be a control, and $x_{2i}$ is the covariate with which we'd like to perform inference against the $y_i$. Both $x_{1i}$ and $x_{2i}$ are binary explanatory variables.

With each combination of binary indicators $(x_{1i}, x_{2i}, y_i)$, counts range from 4 to about 15,000. In particular, when $y_i = 1$, the counts get extremely small (all less than 50). When $y_i = 0$, counts are all above 1,000.

**My goal is to perform inference to get an idea of the association between $x_{2i}$ and $y_i$ when controlling for $x_{1i}$, and not prediction.** How should one handle such a situation? Out-of-the-box logistic regression, I suspect, would not work for this case due to the small group sizes.

I would *strongly* prefer citations to literature that point to how to deal with such a situation, as this is for a paper.

Comment: @BenBolker My fear about logistic regression is that most built-in significance tests in software rely on the Wilks' theorem $\chi^2$ asymptotics. I think that article you sent may help toward that end... thank you for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the main problem with inference from GLMs (such as logistic regression) with small sample sizes (at least in some categories) is the asymptotic nature of [Wilks' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilks%27_theorem) (which underlies p-values based on likelihood ratio tests and confidence intervals based on likelihood profiles). (This asymptotic constraint is *much* weaker than that used in Wald tests, which rely on the asymptotic normality of the sampling distribution of the parameters rather than the asymptotic $\chi^2$ distribution of differences in deviances.)

There is a literature on finite-size corrections under the rubric of *Bartlett corrections*, but the methods are often model-specific and are not widely implemented. Das et al. 2018 review a series of small-sample corrections; they do not provide software ("SAS code available upon request"). One of the options they explore is *Firth correction*, which is implemented in several R packages (`logistf`, `brgml2`) [I know Firth correction provides bias-corrected *point estimates*, I'm not sure how well it extends to inference.]

Another option is *exact logistic regression*; see Zamar et al. 2007 (their `elrm` package, which implements an MCMC computation, is archived on CRAN but can be installed via `remotes::install_version("elrm", "1.2.4")`). They refer to Hirji (2005) for theoretical details.

---

Das, Ujjwal, Subhra Sankar Dhar, and Vivek Pradhan. “Corrected Likelihood-Ratio Tests in Logistic Regression Using Small-Sample Data.” Communications in Statistics - Theory and Methods 47, no. 17 (September 2, 2018): 4272–85. https://doi.org/10.1080/03610926.2017.1373815.

Hirji, Karim F. Exact Analysis of Discrete Data. 1st edition. Boca Raton: Chapman and Hall/CRC, 2005.

Zamar, David, Brad McNeney, and Jinko Graham. “Elrm: Software Implementing Exact-Like Inference for Logistic Regression Models.” Journal of Statistical Software 21, no. 1 (October 8, 2007): 1–18. https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v021.i03.

Comment: There is also higher-order likelihood asymptotics https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cond/vignettes/Rnews-paper.pdf